# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n})=0$

Tags: calculus

I am asked to prove this statement $^{*}$. I am trying now, but it is getting to small and tiny steps that I even loose my way. my steps are as follows: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n})=0^{*}$$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n})=\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}) \cdot (\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[3]{n})}=\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}})^2-(\sqrt[3]{n})^2}{(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[3]{n})}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2n\sqrt{n}+n}}{\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[3]{n}}=\dfrac{(n+\sqrt{n})^{\frac{2}{3}}-n^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(n+\sqrt{n})^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^{\frac{1}{3}}}= .. help = 0$ $$if \quad n\rightarrow \infty$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
Apply for $a=\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt n}$ and $b=\sqrt[3] n$

Comment: how? in my case, it is not cube, but it is cube root. can i easily replace it?

Comment: But you can use the hint as 
$$ (a-b) = \frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2} $$

Comment: oh okay, thanks @macydanim

Comment: now i came to conclusion that $\sqrt{n}<\sqrt[3]{n^2}$, so it converges to $0$, since $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{positive+\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$

Answer (score 3):

What Dennis wrote. Or,
$$
\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}=C\int_n^{n+\sqrt{n}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{2/3}}\leqslant C\int_n^{n+\sqrt{n}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{C'n^{2/3}}=C''n^{1/2-2/3}\to0,
$$
because $1/2\lt2/3$. Likewise, for every positive $A$ and $B$,
$$
\sqrt[A]{n+\sqrt[B]{n}}-\sqrt[A]{n}\to0\iff\frac1A+\frac1B\lt1.
$$